# Cast long to double with non-default rounding mode

Tags: java, ieee-754

In Java, when a long value is cast to double value, the IEEE754 round-to-nearest rounding mode is applied when lossless conversion is not possible.

For example, cast from `1L << 55` or `(1L << 55) + 8` to `double` are lossless. However, any number in between cannot be accurately represented as `double`. The IEEE-754 round-to-nearest (ties to even) rounding mode is applied by default. As a result, `(1L << 55) + 4)` or below will round down where as `(1L << 55) + 5` or up will round up.

Is there any function in standard library or guava that allows me to cast a long to a double using `Round toward +∞` or `Round toward -∞` mode (chosen on a per-callsite basis)? Assuming there isn't one, how do I write such two functions myself efficiently?

Comment: No, Guava doesn't support this, but it probably should.  (It supports the other direction, for example, with [`DoubleMath.roundToLong`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.html#roundToLong-double-java.math.RoundingMode-).)  I plan to file a feature request.

Comment: For future readers: @LouisWasserman filed https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3895.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
static double longRoundUp(long lng)
{
    double d = (double)lng;     
    return lng <= (long)d ? d : Math.nextUp(d);
}

static double longRoundDown(long lng)
{
    double d = (double)lng;     
    return lng >= (long)d ? d : Math.nextDown(d);
}
```

Test:

```
long l1 = (1L << 55);
long l2 = (1L << 55) + 8;
long l3 = (1L << 55) + 4;
long l4 = (1L << 55) + 5;

System.out.format("Up %d %.0f%n", l1, longRoundUp(l1));
System.out.format("Up %d %.0f%n", l2, longRoundUp(l2));
System.out.format("Up %d %.0f%n", l3, longRoundUp(l3));
System.out.format("Up %d %.0f%n", l4, longRoundUp(l4));

System.out.println();
System.out.format("Down %d %.0f%n", l1, longRoundDown(l1));
System.out.format("Down %d %.0f%n", l2, longRoundDown(l2));
System.out.format("Down %d %.0f%n", l3, longRoundDown(l3));
System.out.format("Down %d %.0f%n", l4, longRoundDown(l4));
```

Output:

```
Up 36028797018963968 36028797018963968
Up 36028797018963976 36028797018963976
Up 36028797018963972 36028797018963976
Up 36028797018963973 36028797018963976

Down 36028797018963968 36028797018963968
Down 36028797018963976 36028797018963976
Down 36028797018963972 36028797018963968
Down 36028797018963973 36028797018963968
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.nextUp()` and `Math.nextDown()` may help

```
long a = (1L<<55) + 4;       
long b = (1L<<55) + 5;       

double aa = (double)a;       
double bb = (double)b;       

System.out.println("aa = " +aa);
System.out.println("bb = " +bb);
```

Prints

```
aa = 3.6028797018963968E16
bb = 3.6028797018963976E16
```

```
System.out.println("aa = " + Math.nextUp(aa));
```

Prints

```
aa = 3.6028797018963976E16
```

Comment: How do I write a function that returns the same result for both `aa` and `bb`?